# Godot Onready var not working and getting error Unexpected "Identifier" in class body

Tags: godot, onready

trying to use onready var to start a raycast to play a animation for a npc but even though the ray works it wont play the animation

```
code:

extends Node3D

enum
{
Attack1,
Death1,
Idle,
Pose,
Walk
}

var state = Idle

onready var raycast = $RayCast3D
onready var ap = $"maxdamage_zombie-low-poly"
func _ready():
pass # Replace with function body.


# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(delta):

if raycast.is_colliding():
    state = Attack1
else:
    state = Idle

match state:
    Attack1:
        ap.play("Attack1")
    Death1:
        ap.play("Death1")
    Idle:
        ap.play("Idle")
    Pose:
        ap.play("Pose")
    Walk:
        ap.play("Walk")
```

Explanation/Alternative simple answer on how to fix the code in a beginner/intermediate level     explanation`your text`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by putting a "@" in front of `onready`.

```
@onready var raycast = $RayCast3D
```

https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#onready-annotation

"onready" without the "@" seemed to break for me after upgrading to Godot 4.